# Plot horizontal bars with specific color and thickness

Tags: plotting, charts

I would like to plot bars with specific thickness for each bar like that:
[image]

Is there an easy way to do it?

What I have tried:

```
Plot[{Evaluate[y = 0], Evaluate[y = 1], Evaluate[y = 2]}, {x, -10, 
  10}, PlotStyle -> Thickness[0.035], PlotRange -> {-10, 10}, 
 Axes -> None]
```

Comment: see GridLines, GridLinesStyle

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
values = Sort@RandomSample[Range[10], 6];
colors = {Yellow, Orange, Red, Purple, Magenta, Blue};
```

#### RectangleChart

```
RectangleChart[Thread[{10, Join[{First @ values}, Differences @ values]}], 
 ChartStyle -> "Pastel", PerformanceGoal -> "Speed", 
 ChartLayout -> "Stacked", ChartBaseStyle -> EdgeForm[], Axes -> False]
```

[image]

Use `ChartStyle -> colors` to get

[image]

#### BarChart

```
BarChart[Join[{First@values}, Differences@values], 
 ChartStyle -> "Pastel", PerformanceGoal -> "Speed",  ChartLayout -> "Stacked", 
 ChartBaseStyle -> EdgeForm[], Axes -> False, PlotRange -> {{.5, 1}, Automatic}]
```

[image]

Use `ChartStyle -> colors` to get

[image]

#### StackedListPlot (v11.2)

```
StackedListPlot[Thread /@ Thread[{{0, 1}, Join[{First @ values},
   Differences @ values]}, List, {2}], Axes -> False, PlotStyle -> None] /. 
 Opacity[.2] -> Opacity[1]
```

[image]

Use `PlotStyle -> colors` and post-process to remove the lines:

```
StackedListPlot[Thread /@ Thread[{{0, 1}, Join[{First @ values},
    Differences @ values]}, List, {2}], Axes -> False, PlotStyle -> colors] /.
 Opacity[.2] -> Opacity[1] /. Line[__] :> {}
```

[image]

#### Graphics + Rectangle

```
rects = Rectangle[{0, #}, {10, #2}]& @@@ Partition[Join[{0},values], 2, 1];
colors = {Yellow, Orange, Red, Purple, Magenta, Blue};
Graphics[Transpose[{colors, rects}], AspectRatio -> 1/ GoldenRatio]
```

[image]

Comment: thanks a lot ! How can I change the color ? Could you please specify this specifically ?

Comment: @james, please see the updated version. Replace `colors` with your choice of colors.

Comment: nice ! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @james, my pleasure. Thank you for the accept.

Answer (score 3):

You could plot straight lines, and fill in between them like this,

```
nbars = 5;
values = {1, 5, 6, 7, 10};
Plot[values,
    {x, -5, 5},
    Filling -> Thread[Range[nbars] -> Prepend[Range[nbars - 1], Bottom]],
    FillingStyle -> Directive[Opacity[1]],
    PlotStyle -> None, Axes -> None
]
```

[image]

Comment: thanks a lot ! How can I change the color ?